# Using Android menu code in common Utils File

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I am trying to implement my menu in a `Utils.java` file. Well, so far so good, the menu is appearing as it should although when I click on any menu item, the application stops working. I don't seem to find where the issue is and I would be grateful for your advice. The code for my menu, utils and activity files is as below:

**Utils.java**

```
package com.package.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Utils extends Activity{

private Context _context;

public Utils(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

public void menuSwitch(int item) {
       switch (item) {
            case R.id.menu_one:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class));
            case R.id.menu_two:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MessageActivity.class));
            case R.id.menu_three:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LocateActivity.class));
            case R.id.menu_four:
                startActivity(new Intent(this,
                        AboutActivity.class));
    }
}
}
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_one" android:title="@string/menu_one" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_two" android:title="@string/menu_two" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_three" android:title="@string/menu_three" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_four" android:title="@string/menu_four" />
</menu>
```

**menuActivity.java**

```
package com.package.name;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class DatabaseActivity extends ListActivity {

Utils util;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);

    util = new Utils(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    util.menuSwitch(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't extend `Activity` in your `Utils` class. You need to add `break` after every `case` in your `switch` statement.

Comment: When i don't extend Activity, i get cannot resolve method errors the functions startActivity() and getApplicationContext() functions

Comment: invoking those methods in an Activity which isn't running will throw a NPE. Use could use the context you passed in the Utils constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not extend your `Utils` class. Replace your codes by this one.

```
public class Utils{

private Context _context;

public Utils(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

public void menuSwitch(int item) {
       switch (item) {
            case R.id.menu_one:
                _context.startActivity(new Intent(_context.getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class));
            case R.id.menu_two:
                _context.startActivity(new Intent(_context.getApplicationContext(),
                        MessageActivity.class));
            case R.id.menu_three:
                _context.startActivity(new Intent(_context.getApplicationContext(),
                        LocateActivity.class));
            case R.id.menu_four:
                _context.startActivity(new Intent(_context.getApplicationContext(),
                        AboutActivity.class));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

you are using *startactivity* of Util class , but it should be of the class in which menu is there, thus you should use

```
_context.startactivity(new Intent(_context,wahteverclass.class))
```

Comment: Thanks but what I want to achieve is calling the menu via 1 function and making all changes to the menu in 1 file